# Auto Populate Control on a form with value of the control on another form

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am creating a Microsoft Access 2010 Database. I cannot figure out how to set the value of a textbox when the form loads so that the user does not have to add the foreign key in every time. The user is already open a person record and adding information which is associated to the person they are looking at.

I have a form called PersionView with a field called hdnEDIPI (This is the primary key for the Roster table. It is also the foreign key for the Range table). There is a tab control with a range list box and a button. When the user clicks the button the range form pops up and I would like to auto-populate the tbEDIPI on the range form (The foreign key to match a range to a person) so that the user does not have to re-type the EDIPI in everywhere they would like to associate something to the person they are viewing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this expression as default value of a text control:

```
=Forms![Anotherform Name]![Field Name]
```

The form must be opened or the expression will return a invalid value.

Comment: Thank you! I added this to the Range Form Control Default Value and it worked.